# Global variable in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-scripts

In Sql developer I need to store the variable and use it later how to do that?

```
   VARIABLE liab NUMBER;
    exec select nvl(LIAB_ID,-1)into liab FROM GETM_LIAB_CUST WHERE CUSTOMER_NO = (select   customer_id from apps_master where ACCOUNT_NUMBER='&C' AND BRANCH_CODE = '&B') ;

SPOOL c:\query.SQL
select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID =liab ;' FROM DUAL;
spool off
```

Tried

```
column liabid new_value liab noprint
select nvl(LIAB_ID,-1) liabid FROM GETM_LIAB_CUST WHERE CUSTOMER_NO = (select customer_id from apps_master where ACCOUNT_NUMBER='&C' AND BRANCH_CODE = '&B') ;
```

It doesnt work .Please help me

Comment: What exactly does 'it doesn't work' mean? Error message, missing/wrong output, exploding fireworks... ?

Comment: Hi Frank --
ORA-06550: line 2, column 34:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LIAB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 39:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Please don't put additional information in comments. Edit your question instead (using the "Edit" button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`VARIABLE` declares a bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm), so you need to prefix it with a colon when you refer to it:

```
VARIABLE liab NUMBER;
exec select nvl(LIAB_ID,-1) into :liab FROM ...

SPOOL c:\query.SQL
select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = ' || :liab || ';' FROM DUAL;
spool off
```

You could also do this with a substitution variable instead of a bind variable:

```
column liab new_value g_liab
select nvl(LIAB_ID,-1) as liab FROM ...

SPOOL c:\query.SQL
select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = &g_liab;' FROM DUAL;
spool off
```

The [`column x new_value y` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#i2674387) defines a substitution variable `&y` whose value is set from a column called `x` in a subsequent query.

In both cases SQL Developer will put both the header and the command you ran into the spool file, so you'd see this:

```
> select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = ' || :liab || ';' from dual
'SELECT*FROMGETB_UTILSWHERELIAB_ID='||:LIAB||';'                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = 1;                                        

> spool off
```

You can add `set heading off` and `set echo off`, but if you run it directly from an SQL Worksheet you'd still end up with:

```
> select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = ' || :liab || ';' from dual
SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = 1;
```

To get rid of the echo'd command you'd need to save this as a script and then run that from another worksheet, as was the case with your previous question. So if you had a script called `liab.sql` containing:

```
VARIABLE liab NUMBER;
set feedback off
exec select nvl(LIAB_ID,-1) into :liab FROM ...

set echo off
set heading off
SPOOL c:\query.SQL
select 'SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = ' || :liab || ';' FROM DUAL;
spool off
```

... and then ran that with

```
@liab.sql
```

... the `query.sql` file would contain just:

```
SELECT * FROM GETB_UTILS WHERE LIAB_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Working.Thank you Alex :)

Comment: @user3737084 - as in your previous question you need to run it as a script to allow `set echo off` to take effect, as it behaves the same as `set termout`. I've updated the answer to show the difference.